# What is the area of the shaded region of the square?

Tags: geometry, circles, mathematica

To find area of shaded portion in the below figure, the picture generate by following mathematica code.

[image]

```
Block[{cond = {x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 < 1/4 && x > 0,
    (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 < 1 && x < 1 && y < 1,
    (x - 1)^2 + y^2 < 1 && y > 0 && x < 1}
   },
 RegionPlot[Evaluate@Append[cond, And @@ cond],
    {x, -#, #}, {y, -#, #}, PlotPoints -> 40,
    PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 1.2}},
    PlotStyle -> {None, None, None, Cyan},
    Axes -> 1, Frame -> 0] &@1.5
 ]
```

Comment: I suggest you to use polar coordinates and split the region into two others (or better, they will be congruent) and then use double integrals to compute the area.

Comment: Find the points of intersection, and compute the lengths of the chords joining them. You can get the area of the triangle formed by the chords using [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula); then you're left with three circular segments, and [there are formulas for the areas of those](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), too.

Comment: @Blue Is this is an answer?

Comment: @LokiClock: It's a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leftmost point is $(\frac 12, 1-\frac 2{\sqrt 5})$ and the top point is $(\frac 25,\frac 45)$ from solving simultaneous equations.  Now I would cut the region horizontally at $y=\frac 12$, integrate the area above that line, and double the result.

Comment: Reading Blue's comment, I think that is an easier approach.

Answer (score 4):

As the plots shows we can have the area as follows:

$$A=\int_{y=0.2}^{0.5}\int_{x=1-\sqrt{2y-y^2}}^{\sqrt{y-y^2}}+\int_{y=0.5}^{0.8}\int_{x=1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{y-y^2}}$$

[image]

Comment: Needs a TU! $(+1)$

Comment: Hello, dear friend! How are you today?

Comment: Anything in particular on your mind?

Comment: $\left(\ddot\smile\right)$

Comment: @BabakS.: You make excellent use of graphics! +1

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let [.] denote areas. First, find the positions of $F(\frac25, \frac45)$ and $G(1-\frac{\sqrt3}2, \frac12)$. Then, $\cos\alpha = \frac35$ and $\cos\beta=\frac45$. Evaluate

\begin{align}
[DFC] &= [ABCD] - [DIF] - [CFB] - [ABFI]
 = \frac12 - \frac18\alpha - \frac12\beta\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}[CGH] &= [CGB] - [HGB]
=\frac\pi6 -\frac{\sqrt3}{8} \\
\end{align}

Then, the shaded area

\begin{align}
[FGEJ]&=2(  [DIJ] + [CGH] + [DFC])- [ABCD]\\
& = \frac12\tan^{-1}\frac{11}{2}- \frac{\sqrt3}{4}-\frac{\pi}{24} 
\end{align}